# Shopify Variant checkbox instead of dropdown

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to make it so that my variants are display like the following image instead of the default dropdown Shopify provides.

[image]

I'm currently using the following code, but it throws up an error when trying to add something to the basket. The error states "Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid: id"

```
      <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available == true %}
              <fieldset class="group">
                <ul class="checkbox">
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{variant.id}}">
                      <label>{{ variant.title }} for {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</label>
                    </input>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </fieldset>
            {% else %}
            <option disabled="disabled"> {{ variant.title }} - sold out!</option>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="inpost-buy w-button" value="Add to Bag →"></input>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing your name attribute for the checkbox.

It should have `name="id"`. ( or if you are really determine to have checkboxes and not radio buttons it should be `name="id[]"` )

---

In addition, this is not a valid HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{variant.id}}">
   <label>{{ variant.title }} for {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</label>
</input>
```

You can't have label inside of an input. The other way around will be OK.

---

And there is no point for this, since you are not using select any more:

`<option disabled="disabled"> {{ variant.title }} - sold out!</option>`

Comment: Do you know how I would only show options if the variants are more than 1? e.g. if theres only 1 size there's no point in showing it.

Comment: You can use `{% if product.options.size > 1 %}`.